# getThreadPoolExecutor().getQueue().size() returning zero when running with "@Scheduled"

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using `@Scheduled(fixedDelay=2000)` for one of my methods. This method will run every 2 seconds to check how big the Thread queue is and if it would be less than a certain number it would create new worker threads.

I have the Async configuration class as below

```
@Configuration
@ManagedResource
public class ExecutorConfig {
    @Bean(name = "detailsScraperExecutor")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor getDetailsAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(100);
        // executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(1000000);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("detailsScraperExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Below is my DetailScraper class which contains a method which runs every 2 seconds

```
@Service
public class DetailsScraper {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("detailsScraperExecutor")
    private Executor detailsScraperExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private DetailsScraperAsync scraper;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=2000)
    public void scrapeDetails() {
        System.out.println("Pool size: " + ((ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) detailsScraperExecutor).getThreadPoolExecutor().getQueue().size());

        if (((ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) detailsScraperExecutor).getThreadPoolExecutor().getQueue().size() < 3) {
            System.out.println("NEED TO INCREASE!");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                scraper.run("");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO NEED");
        }

    }
}
```

And below is the thread class

```
@Service
public class DetailsScraperAsync {
    @Async("detailsScraperExecutor")
    public void run(String string) {
        try {
            System.out.println("IN WORKER THREAD");
            Thread.sleep(999999999);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
    }
}
```

Below is the result when I run the application

```
Pool size: 0
NEED TO INCREASE!
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
Pool size: 0
NEED TO INCREASE!
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
Pool size: 0
NEED TO INCREASE!
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
Pool size: 0
NEED TO INCREASE!
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
Pool size: 0
NEED TO INCREASE!
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
Pool size: 0
NEED TO INCREASE!
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
IN WORKER THREAD
```

Why is the pool size showing as zero every time the `scrapeDetails` method is ran?

Comment: Why are you assuming that your @Scheduled function is using `detailsScraperExecutor`? There is no indicator. Comment out this executor and your task will still be scheduled

Comment: @SherifelKhatib but I'm using `@Qualifier("detailsScraperExecutor")`

Answer (score 0):

getQueue().size() shows the queue size, and since setCorePoolSize was 100, the queue stayed 0. Once I reduced the setCorePoolSize to 5, I did see the queue size increasing.